# Convert types of CartoDB georeference on Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bokeh, cartodb

I found a dataframe in Carto web, where the frontier is something like:

```
0106000020E6100000010000000103000000010000001D030000E8ACD8AE0EBDF7BFCD5ADA
E288B5434089C31B1EB0D0F7BFCB057D1C6DB543400E1D88BF88CCF7BFF179B153C2B44340
44AA908B84D6F7BF9D0BCF72F1B343406EFB026F69CFF7BF065C06D547B34340E81D8C7C3D
B5F7BF0BD8C9B95CB34340802C9EE699A7F7BF4844336AF5B343406E59C33BBE97F7BF2320
F7D152B443403422368D7187F7BF87342C4029B443405EAABCA67F77F7BFE03280667EB343
4020A3204F9F7AF7BFE28FBE1450B34340F2D007528D9AF7BFC04AE51506B343406F934569

...
```

I don't know how can I show this frontier in some python libraries like Bokeh or Matplotlib, I would like be able to paint the areas inside the line having an hover with the area's name.

All the examples I've found come from a public dataset inside the libraries, but I don't have it

Answer (score 0):

This should be WKB binary, Shapely library can decode it, see https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=wkb#shapely.wkb.loads